# Handeling JSON in Laravel controller

Tags: json, laravel

I'm new to Laravel and kinda new to JQuery too so bear with me please.  So in one of my views I have a form :

```
<table id="tblAShip" class="report table table-condensed table-hover table-sorter">
<thead class="no-sort">
    <tr>
        <th>Height</th>
        <th>Width</th>
        <th>Length</th>
        <th>Weight</th>
        <th>Create parcel</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="height" name="height" type="number" /></td>
        <td><input id="width" name="width" type="number" /></td>
        <td><input id="length" name="length" type="number" /></td>
        <td><input id="weight" name="weight" type="number" /></td>
        <td><input type="button" name ="creatShip" id="creatShip" value="Ajouter"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Then this form is handled by a JS that makes an Ajax call

```
function creerParcel(){
var docNum = $("#commandeNum").val();

var hei = $("#height").val();
var wid = $("#width").val();
var len = $("#length").val();
var wei = $("#weight").val();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/EasyPostNetBanks/Shipment/"+docNum,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    processData: false,
    data: {
        "Parcels":[{
            "length": len,
            "width": wid,
            "height": hei,
            "weight": wei }]
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {

    },
    success: function(data){
    }
});
```

then in my controller I try go retreive this data to create a shipment with the parcel information i got from my Ajax call

```
foreach(\Input::get('Parcels') as $parcelInfo)
    {
        $parcel = $this->CreateParcel($parcelInfo);

        $shipment =  Shipment::create(array(
            "to_address" => $to,
            "reference"=>$idCommande,
            "from_address" => $from,
            "parcel" => $parcel,
            "options" => array("label_format" => "ZPL")
        ));

        $ship = \Shipments::creer($shipment);
        $shipments[] =  $ship;
    }
```

but my \Input::get('Parcels') is always NULL\n.  How is it possible?  I've tried almost everything i could find online but to no avail so here I am (first post BTW. Hi all!).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried viewing the network tab in a browser, to see if everything is being sent up to the server in the way you're expecting? For example, in Chrome open the inspection panel, usually right click and then choose "Inspect Element". Then look in the "Network" tab to see exactly what is being sent to the server.

If the ajax post looks correct, then it will help narrow down exactly where the problem lies. If it's not the front end, try die and dump `dd($variable)` on the entire post results.

You can do that by using the following somewhere in the controller.

```
dd(Input::all());
```

Comment: I get an error 500 in my network table, dd(Input::all()) does not work (because of the lack of input I guess).
the laravel.log give me this
Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'Invalid argumen...', '/var/www/EasyPo...', 85, Array)

Answer (score 0):

OK, turns out it was my processData: false, that caused the problem, silly me.